# Otros LogViewer - Searching and sorting by method, class or message

Tags: log4j, otroslogviewer

I am starting to work with Otros Log Viewer to analyze my log4j logs, 
but couldn't find a way to filter the logs by methods or class names, and couldn't find a way (for example) to count how many errors were made in method "foo".

I would appreciate a nice solution \ tip.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To currently class filter do not support filtering by method. You can implement your own filter, here is [wiki page](https://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer/wiki/ImplementingLogFilter).

You can enable [Experimental features](https://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer/wiki/ExperimentalFeatures) by adding  `<loadExperimentalFeatures>true</loadExperimentalFeatures>`
 to config. It will enable some experimental features like Query filter. It works the same as Query search. On wiki you will find how to construct query: https://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer/wiki/SearchEvents. Query can look like this `method==run && class~=my.packet`

You can also use search with "Query mode" and use query: `method==run && class~=my.packet` and click "Mark all found" and on status bar message like 233 message marked with ....